How much context should I include in a button label?

I am looking to understand best practices for deciding how much context a button should include in its label for screen readers.
My current scenario I have a repeating row with a user generated question and two icon buttons (edit and delete).
I am wondering if a simple Edit and Delete label is sufficient or if I should be more prescriptive as to what is being edited and deleted with each button.  For example, Edit {question} question and Delete {question} question where {question} is the user value.

I think your question has two different approaches, the one where you need to include accessibility for your users with assistive technology and the other where your users don't use assistive technology.
The text for your labels should be clear for the user and avoid extensive text that could be disturbing while appearing in the UI. Your first option Edit and Delete are sufficient to comply with the standards. If you want to go further and try "Delete Question" and "Edit Question", your text would be short enough to don't block other elements in the screen.
You can use alt text on your code that must be understandable and let the user what the next action is going to be performed. For example, if the user is using a screen reader, the reader must read the question and if user tabs to the next element the text must indicate "Delete Question" or "Edit Question". It is not necessary to put "Delete What is the biggest planet in the Solar System question" That would be redundant for the user.

In general, you should be careful with adding extra, non-visible information. Unless you are communicating to children, the context will often be clear. If the context is not clear for AT users, then you probably need to communicate better, overall.
WCAG 2.4.6 Headings and labels:"Headings and labels describe topic or purpose."
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#headings-and-labels
The supporting "Underestand..." and "How to meet..." documents, should be good for your purpose:
